# Installation problems on a domain-name-less server

Tags: installation, domain

Is it possible to install WordPress on a public server that doesn't have a domain name configured yet? I thought I'd set it up on IP-only, and had the line `server_name _;` in my Nginx configuration. I think it's because of this that the WordPress installation dies at `wp-admin/install.php?step=2` and I see the following error in the Nginx logs:

```
2017/01/08 07:24:53 [error] 25686#25686: *22 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught phpmailerException: Invalid address: wordpress@_ in /home/ankush/wp_main_site/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php:946
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ankush/wp_main_site/wp-includes/pluggable.php(352): PHPMailer->setFrom('wordpress@_', 'WordPress', false)
#1 /home/ankush/wp_main_site/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php(395): wp_mail('dkasolutions.sa...', 'New WordPress S...', 'Your new WordPr...')
```

Is a domain name a must or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `server_name` to the IP address, eg:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name 0.1.2.3;
    // other stuff
}
```

You could also leave it out, because the default in ngninx is an empty string. But then all those pieces in WordPress that don't validate `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and similar values … will just break.

See ticket [#25239](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25239) for the progress on this front.

If only WordPress had a `Request` object, like everyone else. Then it would be easy to prepare all these global values. See [Symfony for an example](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/75acea00ecf498cbb65da48916d622dea1edc3e1/Request.php#L335).

Comment: `If only WordPress had a Request object, like everyone else.` I don't know Symphony, but WordPress has `WP_Http` class. What is missing in there?

Comment: @prosti That's a completely different thing. A Request object provides a standardized interface for the (sanitized) request data. It also makes tests easier, because you can simulate different requests.

Comment: @prosti You are aware that this is just a placeholder?

Comment: Yes, but someone will copy paste and better to use 1.2.3.4 @toscho

Comment: @prosti How is 1.2.3.4 better then? It is wrong too. If you are able to edit that file, you should know what you are doing. This is a developer site.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to install WordPress on a public server that doesn't have a domain name configured yet?

Yes.

> I thought I'd set it up on IP-only, and had the line server_name _; in my Nginx configuration.

You can use server name you like, for instance.

```
server_name tattarrattat.com;
```

Your WordPress installation can be aware of the server name `tattarrattat.com`.

On your end you can set inside your `/etc/hosts` file something like this.

```
1.2.3.4 tattarrattat.com
```

Where 1.2.3.4 is your server IP address. 
So even thought you test on a remote server you use the domain you like.

---

You may also use [Virtual Hosts extension](https://www.google.rs/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjY09_X1LXRAhXG1iwKHRedAl4QFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fvirtual-hosts%2Faiehidpclglccialeifedhajckcpedom%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNFHTlFFN02giViPAAn4b8408DjXJg&sig2=srnBD8jOIHig4Y5E-9luwA) in Chrome, when previewing the web site on your end.

Comment: I've looked into this solution but changing hosts file isn't always possible, especially when you have to show the website in progress to clients. I needed something that will work right out of the box.

Comment: It depends on how you define *right out of the box*? I am just providing some tips from the heart. Should be good when creating website test environment clones.